# Draw Line in UIImageView by using CGPoints

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, cgcontext

I have an imageView and i want to draw lines on image in that imageView using CGPoints but i am getting errors like: invalid context etc.. any solution to draw lines without CGContext approach.

```
CGContextRef cntxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(cntxt, p1.x, p1.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(cntxt, p2.x, p2.y);
CGContextStrokePath(cntxt);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely attempting to draw outside of `drawRect:`. If you check the value of `cntxt`, it is likely `NULL`. A draw context is created prior to calling `drawRect:` and is destroyed afterwards. There is generally no "current context" outside of this function.

You need to keep track of your points in a data structure. In `drawRect:`, you will then do whatever drawing you need to do based on that data.

Comment: yes i am not using drawRect method as i am doing this in UIViewController subclass. drawRect method is available in UIView subclass

Comment: UIViewController can't draw anything at all. It's not a view. Your view controller should generally hold onto the relevant data, and pass it to the view for drawing.

Comment: Thanks Rob I did it in a UIView class and i got what i wanted..  :)